# What's the difference between an ESLInt plugin and an ESLInt rule? To create a customized rule, do we have to create our own plugin first?

Tags: javascript, frontend, eslint, jslint

Could someone explain the difference between an ESLInt plugin and an ESLInt rule. I did my research on https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins#working-with-plugins and it seems like a plugin is a collection of rules. It says

```
Plugins can expose additional rules for use in ESLint
```

However I wonder does this imply that plugins can have other usage, other than storing a bunch of rules?

Also if I were to write my own ESLint rule, do I need to first create my own ESLint plugin? I suppose I cannot just modify any existing ESLint rules on any existing ESLint plugins right?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189200/whats-the-difference-between-plugins-and-extends-in-eslint

Answer (score 0):

I mean what else do you want to do besides store things related to eslint?

You can configure rules, environments, configs, and pre-processors in them.

The term plugin in this context is typically reserved for eslint rules, however you can also extend a plugin (https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/.eslintrc) and configure additional rules that override it.