# ESLint extends vs plugins v2020

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

There's answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189200/whats-the-difference-between-plugins-and-extends-in-eslint) which in my opinion doesn't actually answers the question, on the difference between `extends: []` vs `plugins: []` in ESLint.

In my case, i just used extends section:

```
extends: [
  'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
],
plugins: [],
rules: {
  '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': [
    'error',
    {
      allowExpressions: true,
    },
  ],
}
```

As you can see, i just used predefined config from `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended` and also overwritten `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` rule in `rules: {}` section. But why do we need this PLUGINS section then? If everything works without it? What do i miss?

Answer (score 17):

You have done it correctly.

For your example, there are 2 ways to do add `typescript-eslint`...

- 1st way:

```js
{
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: { sourceType: "module" },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  extends: [],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        allowExpressions: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- 2nd way:

```js
{
  plugins: [],
  extends: ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      {
        allowExpressions: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The difference is...

- 1st way:

  - `parser`, `parserOptions` and `plugins` are manually added,
  - Only `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` is enforced.
- 2nd way:

  - `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended` has automatically added `parser`, `parserOptions` and `plugins`.
  - Recommended typescript rules are added and enforced.
  - `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` is augmented and enforced.

This is why when you use `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`, things work normally even if `plugins` is empty. A well-written plugins/configs allows that to happen.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that if I add something under `extend:`, adding it under `plugins:` as well is unnecessary. I think that's not right. In a project I'm working on, I've just removed a plugin from `plugins` (and left it as it was in `extends:`). Now I get `eslint` errors saying `Definition for rule 'xxxxx' was not found.`

Comment: @LGenzelis I think it depends on the plugin and how the plugin author implemented it, which is a bit annoying as it means you can never be sure if a plugin will work without adding it to `plugins` or not.