# Issues trying to extend ESLint in a create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

Create-react-app allows you to extend the ESLint config that comes with create-react-app:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config

However when I try to do this in my own project i just get this error
([Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw8h1.png))

#### Error

`Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-shared-config'`

#### Command run

`eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .`

#### .eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "shared-config"],
  "rules": {
    "additional-rule": "warn"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
      "rules": {
        "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you set the documented env var?

Comment: yep, added a .env file with `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` in

Comment: I think the example is just showing how you *could* do that, not saying there *is* a config named shared-config.

Comment: You might be right however i changed it to `eslint:recommended` instead and im still getting a similar error `Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safe way to setup a base ESLint config file to build upon is by following the [ESLint usage guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)

```sh
$ npx eslint --init
# or
$ yarn run eslint --init
```

Like @jonrsharpe said, `shared-config` is just an example that cannot be used literally, the docs was trying to explain that you could use shared configurations.

For example, if you add an ESLint plugin with a `shared-config` rule set, then you could use that as indicated by the example.

> [Difference between plugins and extends in ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189200/whats-the-difference-between-plugins-and-extends-in-eslint)

> [`EXTEND_ESLINT` flag was removed in react-scripts v4](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)