# eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y for Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, accessibility, eslint

I am trying to setup for my typescript react project that while I am working it will give me warnings/errors if I am doing something that is not accessible. My editor already gives me listing errors, but I tried setting up eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y and I just cannot get it to work.

Here is the eslint section in my package.json

```json
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "shared-config",
      "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.ts?(x)"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean *just cannot get it to work*?

From the looks of it, I'm guessing you are missing the `plugins` key that is required to use any given plugin per eslint [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-a-configuration-from-a-plugin).

The `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` docs even mentions this in the [usage](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y#usage) section.

The `extends` key only applies a ruleset whereas the `plugins` key makes certain rules available, see a longer explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522973/6943587).

```json
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "shared-config",
      "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "jsx-a11y"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.ts?(x)"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> If this doesn't work please elaborate on what isn't working or what errors you get.

Comment: Yeah the plugins is what was missing. After I posted this, I figured it out, lol. Thanks for reply

Answer (score -1):

first lets make sure you have all
install this modules

```json
"devDependencies": {
"@types/eslint": "7.28.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
"babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
"eslint": "7.30.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "12.3.1",
"eslint-config-react-app": "6.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "5.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "24.3.6",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-testing-library": "3.10.2",
"eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",}
```

when you install them modules at yow scripts section add a new prop like this one

```
"lint": "eslint --config ./.eslintrc.js \"./src/**/*.ts\" \"./src/**/*.tsx\" --fix --color"
```

here is a functional example

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "react-app",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    ],
    "env": {
        "browser": false,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "import",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "react",
        "react-hooks",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "createClass": "createReactClass", // Regex for Component Factory to use,
            // default to "createReactClass"
            "pragma": "React", // Pragma to use, default to "React"
            "fragment": "Fragment", // Fragment to use (may be a property of <pragma>), default to "Fragment"
            "version": "detect", // React version. "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
            // You can also use `16.0`, `16.3`, etc, if you want to override the detected value.
            // default to latest and warns if missing
            // It will default to "detect" in the future
            "flowVersion": "0.53" // Flow version
        },
        "propWrapperFunctions": [
            // The names of any function used to wrap propTypes, e.g. `forbidExtraProps`. If this isn"t set, any propTypes wrapped in a function will be skipped.
            "forbidExtraProps",
            {
                "property": "freeze",
                "object": "Object"
            },
            {
                "property": "myFavoriteWrapper"
            }
        ],
        "componentWrapperFunctions": [
            // The name of any function used to wrap components, e.g. Mobx `observer` function. If this isn"t set, components wrapped by these functions will be skipped.
            "observer", // `property`
            {
                "property": "styled"
            }, // `object` is optional
            {
                "property": "observer",
                "object": "Mobx"
            },
            {
                "property": "observer",
                "object": "<pragma>"
            } // sets `object` to whatever value `settings.react.pragma` is set to
        ],
        "linkComponents": [
            // Components used as alternatives to <a> for linking, eg. <Link to={ url } />
            "Hyperlink",
            {
                "name": "Link",
                "linkAttribute": "to"
            }
        ]
     },
    rules": {
// yow rules
   }
};
```