# Is this the difference between an eslint-config and eslint-plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, lint, eslintrc

I have been reading various documentation to try to understand the difference between why we add an eslint-plugin and why we might use an eslint-config, I've found it quite confusing but this is my understanding if someone can please confirm or correct.

eslint-config packages are installed as they contain a configuration of a standard set of baseline rules provided by eslint which have been customised in some way eg the airbnb config.

eslint-plugin packages are installed as they cover new rules only which aren't in the baseline set of rules provided by eslint eg for using libraries like react or vue.

Am I correct in this understanding?

Comment: I think you are correct. [A config, is usually a set of rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-configuration-files), and [a plugin is the addition of a new specific rule](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/plugins#plugins).

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[What's the difference between plugins and extends in eslint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189200/whats-the-difference-between-plugins-and-extends-in-eslint)"?